# Which countries are at a prolonged war?

Tags: armed-conflict, international, treaty, peace-treaty

So I've just discovered Russia and Japan are still at war as they never signed the WW2 treaty. They are apparently hoping to get all 4 of the islands seized during the war back, but only 2 of them were specified in the treaty thus they did not sign. Though they did having a meeting regarding this last year.

There is also Syria and Israel which seems to be just due to hatred and unwillingness to negotiate with the Golan Heights.

So I am wondering if there are any other countries in the same vein? If the reason is known for the lack of a peace treaty would also be appreciated!

Also I would describe prolonged war in this context as being officially at war with no combat for over the span of 5 years.

Comment: There is a wonderful (but sadly apocryphal) story that the English town of Berwick-upon-Tweed was [at war with Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berwick-upon-Tweed#Relations_with_Russia) for 113 years, from 1853 to 1966.

Comment: How do you feel about a conflict which has an armistice agreement, but no peace treaty?

Comment: @origimbo Sounds good as well though I can imagine there being quite a few more of those.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit The English are brilliant at that. The British Isles of Scilly have been at war with the Netherlands for [**335 years**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Hundred_and_Thirty_Five_Years%27_War) from 30 March 1651 – 17 April 1986.

Comment: Sovereignty of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibraltar has been disputed for some time now.

Comment: @barrycarter: A dispute over sovereignty isn't a war. The UK and Spain are close military allies (both being members of NATO) and have not been at war since 1807.

Comment: OK, I'll provide some wp pages you've probably already seen instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_extended_by_diplomatic_irregularity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_longest_wars

Answer (score 0):

North and South Korea are still technically in a state of war - there was only a truce signed, not an official end to the conflict. Occasionally, N Korea will launch small attacks against S Korea - the odd border flareup, or naval actions such as the one portrayed in the film Northern Limit Line. That is the one official war that is still going on.

India and Pakistan are at odds with each other, have been since 1947. Both have nuclear weapons, so that is always an interesting one to watch.

Comment: perhaps you could add some sources about the official state of war and last 'combat' for some particular definition.